# How do you join integer fields that BigQuery has assigned different types to?

Tags: google-bigquery

While trying to join two tables ('A' and 'B') on a numeric field, and where each table has the exact same range of values, I get the following error:

Error: Fields X and Y have unequal types TYPE_INT64 and TYPE_INT32, so they can't be join attributes.

It's not possible to join on INTEGER(A.X) = B.Y because only field names are accepted, not arbitrary expressions. Casting A.X in a subquery works, but the performance is very poor since it is the larger table; casting B.Y does not work, which seems inconsistent with the error message (implying Y is 32-bit) and the documentation for the INTEGER function (converts to 64-bit). Could this be a bug?

Comment: What is generating an int32? We should be applying the cast automatically.

Comment: @JordanTigani If you have an integer literal (`SELECT 0 as xxx`), it seems to come out as an int32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is the cast in the subquery. The real problem with join performance is not the cast but an inefficiency in the join algorithm. This is currently being addressed, but is taking longer since it is part of a larger query execution engine change.